# Python SQL как записывать в базу

Tags: django, sqlite, python-3.6

```
import re

with open("/home/usr/base.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        data = line.split(";")
        test=re.findall('(?:\+|\d+)[\d\-\(\) ]{9,}\d+', data[0])
        print(test)
        # записать test и data[1] в базу 

есть файл со строками типа    
+1 213-295-2378; Mark James 
+16073583231; Restut niss
как мне записать test и data[1] в базу 
в базе поля "phone" и "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться механизмом миграций и возможностью выполнять произвольный код во время миграции.

Для начала необходимо создать пустой файл миграции для приложения содержащего модель которую нужно заполнить данными:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty <имя приложения>
```

В директории приложения есть папка migrations в которой после выполнения предыдущей команды появится новый файл примерно такого содержания:

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (<имя приложения>, '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

Номер миграции может отличаться если вы ранее уже делали миграции.

Из доступных операций потребуется [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) которая ожидает два вызываемых объекта (в нашем случае это будут функции) в качестве аргументов.
Первую функцию используем для загрузки данных, вторая понадобится если вы захотите откатить миграцию.

Эти функции также принимает два аргумента, нас интересует первый - это список приложений.

В итоге файл с миграцией будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
from django.db import migrations
import re


# Логика для загрузки данных
def load_initial_data(apps, schema_editor):
    # название модели для примера Model
    # замените на используемое в вашем приложении
    Model = apps.get_model("<имя приложения>", "Model")

    initial_data = []

    # код из вашего примера
    with open("/home/usr/base.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            data = line.split(";")
            test = re.findall('(?:\+|\d+)[\d\-\(\) ]{9,}\d+', data[0])
            initial_data.append(Model(phone=test, name=data[1]))

    Model.objects.bulk_create(initial_data)


# логика для отката миграции
def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Model = apps.get_model("<имя приложения>", "Model")

    Model.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_initial_data, reverse_func)
    ]
```

Далее применяете миграцию:

```
python manage.py migrate
```